# How can I use the clang atomics library on Windows?

Tags: windows, clang, llvm-clang

I have a program, the simplified version of which is below:

```
struct T {
    char data[17]; // Really, anything larger than 16 bytes
};

int main() {
    _Atomic(struct T) atomic;

    atomic = (struct T) {};

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile this program on Windows, then I get this error:

```
C:> clang test.c
test-95dcb2.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __atomic_store referenced in function main
a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In the clang documentation, there's a note that says you need to use the `-latomic` linker flag if `_Atomic` can't be compiled down to machine instructions, as in this case. That flag doesn't work on Windows, though:

```
test-95dcb2.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __atomic_store referenced in function main
a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Clang 3.9.1. Is there a way to make this work, or is it not supported on Windows yet?